# Difference between two Iterator<Range<usize>>'s

Tags: algorithm, rust, range

My program represents sets as `Iterator<Range<usize>>`, and I'm trying to implement set subtraction.

Essentially, I'm trying to create a function `set_diff` such that:

```
let a = vec![1..5, 7..10];
let a = a.into_iter();

let b = vec![3..9];
let b = b.into_iter();

let mut c = set_diff(a, b);
assert_eq!(c.next(), Some(1..3));
assert_eq!(c.next(), Some(9..10));
assert_eq!(c.next(), None);
```

This is complicated by the fact that this code should run with `#[no_std]`. The real iterators `a` and `b` are able to be cloned, if that helps.

I've made a probably-working iterator for the difference of two ranges, below. The only possible solution I've thought of would be to flatmap this over each element of A for every element in B, but that's really inefficient.

```
use std::cmp::{max, min};
use std::ops::Range;

/// An extension for Ranges allowing subtraction.
pub trait RangeExt<T: Ord> {
    fn difference(self, other: Self) -> DiffIter<T>;
}

impl RangeExt<usize> for Range<usize> {
    fn difference(self, other: Range<usize>) -> DiffIter<usize> {
        DiffIter {
            state: Some(match (self.start < other.start, self.end < other.end) {
                (false, false) => DiffIterState::One(Range {
                    start: max(other.end, self.start),
                    end: self.end,
                }),
                (false, true) => DiffIterState::None,
                (true, false) => DiffIterState::Two(Range {
                    start: self.start,
                    end: other.start,
                }, Range {
                    start: other.end,
                    end: self.end,
                }),
                (true, true) => DiffIterState::One(Range {
                    start: self.start,
                    end: if other.start == self.end {
                        self.end
                    } else {
                        min(other.start - 1, self.end)
                    }
                }),
            })
        }
    }
}

/// A iterator for the difference of two ranges.
pub struct DiffIter<T> {
    state: Option<DiffIterState<T>>,
}

impl<T> Iterator for DiffIter<T> {
    type Item = Range<T>;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Range<T>> {
        let (out, next) = match self.state.take().unwrap() {
            DiffIterState::None => {
                (None, DiffIterState::None)
            },
            DiffIterState::One(r) => {
                (Some(r), DiffIterState::None)
            },
            DiffIterState::Two(l, r) => {
                (Some(l), DiffIterState::One(r))
            },
        };
        self.state = Some(next);
        out
    }
}

enum DiffIterState<T> {
    None,
    One(Range<T>),
    Two(Range<T>, Range<T>),
}
```

Comment: A few questions: (1) are the `Iterator<Range<usize>>` guaranteed to have non-overlapping ranges, (2) are they guaranteed to have their ranges ordered and (3) what have you tried so far?

Comment: Edited to show what I tried before sleeping.

Comment: @MatthieuM (1) yes, (2) I believe A is, B is definitely not, (3) edited

Comment: If B isn't sorted, you are in trouble. The simplest solution I can think of is `collect`ing all the ranges into a `Vec`, sorting it, and then iterating over *that*. Unfortunately, the `Vec` itself cannot be stored into the resulting iterator, so you first need to create a `struct` and then implement `IntoIterator` for it to yield your special `Iterator`.